# Azure Recovery Services VM replication between availability zones (single region) with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

With the option to use availability zones instead of regions as Disaster Recovery source / targets for the Recovery Services Vault VM replication, it appears this is not possible to implement this with Terraform yet.

Is this the case?

There doesn't seem to be any reference to zones in azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm.

All the TF documentation references using a separate region for this feature, although the notes on AzureRM v3.0 do mention adding "zones" parameter to any object that supports it.

Does anyone know if the Azure API supports this yet or do we have to just wait for TF to be updated?

Comment: You may need to raise this as a feature request for the Azure provider.

Comment: The v3.0 statement is a little vague IMO. It says they'll add consistency to resources that support zones.
I'm not sure if this means they will make zones available in this resource provider but I hope so.

Comment: Correct .. ARM templates support the target availability zones parameter .. but terraform doesn't .. I have raised a issue in there repo . you can refer https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if the Azure API supports this yet or do we have to
> just wait for TF to be updated?

Azure API supports it as it can be done using ***Bicep*** or ***ARM template*** but the parameter `target_availability_zone` which is required when you are trying the zone to zone disaster recovery for a VM is not present in Terraform.

As a ***Workaround*** you can use [`azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group_template_deployment) and use the Bicep/ARM template which is mentioned in this [***`Microsoft Documentation`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.recoveryservices/2021-08-01/vaults/replicationfabrics/replicationprotectioncontainers/replicationprotecteditems?tabs=bicep#enableprotectionproviderspecificinput-objects) as per your requirement.

I have raised ***[`Github issue`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14652)*** to address the same for adding the argument `target_availabiltity_zone` in `azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm` resource block.